# Floor or ceiling of a pandas series in python?

Tags: python, pandas, series, floor, ceil

I have a pandas series `series`.  If I want to get the element-wise floor or ceiling, is there a built in method or do I have to write the function and use apply?  I ask because the data is big so I appreciate efficiency.  Also this question has not been asked with respect to the Pandas package.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can use NumPy's built in methods to do this: `np.ceil(series)` or `np.floor(series)`.

Both return a Series object (not an array) so the index information is preserved.

Comment: how can I chain this like using `round()` on a pandas `Series`?

Comment: This works: dataframe["new_series"] = np.ceil(dataframe[series].round(0))

Comment: @iamyojimbo, if you want to chain the method, use `pipe()`, `df['column'].pipe(np.ceil)`

Answer (score 38):

I am the OP, but I tried this and it worked:

```
np.floor(series)
```

Answer (score 23):

> **UPDATE: THIS ANSWER IS WRONG, DO NOT DO THIS**
>
> Explanation: using `Series.apply()` with a native vectorized Numpy function makes
> no sense in most cases as it will run the Numpy function in a Python loop, leading to much worse performance. You'd be much better off using
> `np.floor(series)` directly, as suggested by several other answers.

You could do something like this using NumPy's floor, for instance, with a `dataframe`:

```
floored_data = data.apply(np.floor)
```

Can't test it right now but an actual and working solution might not be far from it.

Comment: If you use the argument `raw=True` then the [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function will achieve much better performance.

Comment: The apply function is not a vectorized implementation therefore it will be super slow. You can call np.floor directly to the dataframe.

Answer (score 19):

With [`pd.Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html#pandas.Series.clip), you can set a floor via `clip(lower=x)` or ceiling via `clip(upper=x)`:

```py
s = pd.Series([-1, 0, -5, 3])
    
print(s.clip(lower=0))
# 0    0
# 1    0
# 2    0
# 3    3
# dtype: int64
    
print(s.clip(upper=0))
# 0   -1
# 1    0
# 2   -5
# 3    0
# dtype: int64
```

`pd.Series.clip` allows generalised functionality, e.g. applying and flooring a ceiling *simultaneously*, e.g. `s.clip(-1, 1)`

*NOTE*: Answer originally referred to [`clip_lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip_lower.html) / [`clip_upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip_upper.html) which were [removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html) in pandas 1.0.0.

Comment: I can see that it's worth mentioning `clip` et al. as *somewhat* related functions, but clipping a value is a very different operation to finding the floor/ceiling of that value...

Comment: @AlexRiley, Point taken; the reason I mention it is there are situations where the upper and lower bounds are variables from an external input, and you may want (for example) to use `s.clip(-1, np.inf)` or `s.clip(-np.inf, 1)` to handle those situations seamlessly.

Comment: It was more that I was puzzled by what OP's wants to do given the wording of their question (and indeed OP's own answer). Unless I'm missing something, if you have `s = pd.Series([3.1, 2.2, 5.6])` there does not seem to be a way to use `clip` alone to compute the same result as `np.floor(s)` for example. (Not to detract from your answer which is well-written and useful information - I was just confused when I reread the question.)

Comment: @AlexRiley, Ah, now rereading the question is confusing me also. I came by the question when googling "how to floor a Pandas series". So I'll leave this answer for others who reach the somewhat ambiguous question via the same route!

Answer (score 9):

The pinned answer already the fastest. Here's I provide some alternative to do ceiling and floor using pure pandas and compare it with the numpy approach.

```
series = pd.Series(np.random.normal(100,20,1000000))
```

**Floor**

```
%timeit np.floor(series) # 1.65 ms ± 18.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit series.astype(int) # 2.2 ms ± 131 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit (series-0.5).round(0) # 3.1 ms ± 47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit round(series-0.5,0) # 2.83 ms ± 60.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Why astype int works? Because in Python, when converting to integer, that it always get floored.

**Ceil**

```
%timeit np.ceil(series) # 1.67 ms ± 21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit (series+0.5).round(0) # 3.15 ms ± 46.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit round(series+0.5,0) # 2.99 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So yeah, just use the numpy function.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily calculate the floor without using numpy, by calling:

```
series.astype(int)
```

This type conversion to int uses the floor operator.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are limited. They either error on or incorrectly handle NaNs in the input_series.

You can correctly handle these cases with

```py
# setup
input_series = pd.Series([pd.NA, pd.NA,3,4,5.4,pd.NA,5.3,7])

# floor all non-nans in input
mask_nan = input_series.isna()
input_series.where(mask_nan, np.floor(input_series[~mask_nan]))

# gives [<NA>, <NA>, 3, 4, 5, <NA>, 5, 7]
```

Important:

- use pandas `.isna()` to future-proof the ongoing pandas NA dtype changes
- use pandas where not `np.where` so we can operate on a subset for the replacement series
- np.floor() for speed