# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> when using math.ceil

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, math

I have data looks like this:

```
    order_number    ship_distance   delivery_fee    utilization remaining_multiplier_type
     R000001943        3.818           11.25            LOW            DISCOUNT
     R000002604        5.993           7.00             NaN            NaN
     R000005277        2.942           7.00             NaN            NaN
     R000006010        8.289           9.50             NaN            NaN
     R000010127        3.233           6.00             NaN            BASE
```

I'm trying to round up the value in column ship_distance using the math and numpy.

Using `data = math.ceil(data[ship_distance']` I got error `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`
When using `data = np.ceil(data['ship_distance'])` I don't get the desired result.

Expected result:

```
 order_number   ship_distance   delivery_fee    utilization   remaining_multiplier_type 
  R000001943          4            11.25             LOW           DISCOUNT                  
  R000002604          6            7.00              NaN           NaN                       
  R000005277          3            7.00              NaN           NaN                       
  R000006010          9            9.50              NaN           NaN                       
  R000010127          4            6.00              NaN           BASE
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Floor or ceiling of a pandas series in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592456/floor-or-ceiling-of-a-pandas-series-in-python)

Comment: All the `math` functions only work with one number, not a Series (column) or array.  What was wrong with the `np.ceil`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# np.ceil(data['ship_distance'])
data['ship_distance'] = data['ship_distance'].apply(lambda X: int(math.ceil(X)))

print(data)
```

Comment: thanks...it works..why I should use lambda?do you mind explaining?

Comment: To convert float to int I used lambda or you can also try the .astype() method to convert an entire pandas column datatype.

Comment: There's no real need for the lambda here: `math.ceil` is already a function that takes a float and returns the ceiling as an `int`, so `data['ship_distance'].apply(math.ceil)` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy:

```
np.ceil(df["ship_distance"]).astype("int64")
```

Comment: had tried...but I doesn't give me the desired result...Got the following result
27       3.0
1453    13.0
1630    17.0
1857     5.0
2016     1.0
Name: ship_distance, dtype: float64