# How to rounds a given number up to the nearest specified multiple using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

May I know if there exist build-in Pandas module to  rounds a given number up to the nearest specified multiple.

In excel this can be achieved using `Ceiling function`.

Say given a df of `-0.4, 0.5,1.5`, then round this to a multiple of 1 will result in `0,1,and 2`.

While I have comb the net about this topic, but I dont see any reference about it. Please let me know if this is a duplicate.

Other might suggest something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272149/round-to-5-or-other-number-in-python) but its not a built in Pandas

Comment: `np.ceil(df)` or `np.ceil(serie)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```py
> import math as m
> [m.ceil(n) for n in [-0.4, 0.5, 1.5]]
[0, 1, 2]
```

With dataframe

```py
> import pandas as pd
> df = pd.DataFrame([-0.4, 0.5, 1.5], columns=['numbers'])
> df.apply(m.ceil, axis=1)
0    0
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Then without `apply`

```
> import numpy as np
> np.ceil(df['numbers'])
0   -0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
Name: numbers, dtype: float64
```

Actually, you can also get a similar result only with operations.

```py
> df // 1 + 1
    numbers
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the OP present the data in term of dataframe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: It seems external module is still require then.

Comment: @balandongiv, maybe not, I added one without external modules.

Comment: plus one for that, maybe that answered why there is no built in function for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this was answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592456/floor-or-ceiling-of-a-pandas-series-in-python), not specifically with pandas, but with numpy, although I think this is the behavior you are looking for.